# ES6 / Babel spread error with Set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code, simplified from a real-world example.

```
let arr = [0,1,2],
    s = new Set(arr);

let arr2 = [...s];
alert('3 == ' + arr2.length);
```

The problem is that this fails, and produces an empty arr2 on Google Chrome which has a native Set implementation, but a polyfilled Array.from.  Amusingly, it works properly on IE11, which has a polyfilled Array.from AND Set.

Babel converts the spread Set to this

```
var arr2 = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(s));
```

and `_toConsumableArray` returns `Array.from`.  I've set a breakpoint inside of `_toConsumableArray` and I can see it producing an empty Array through the call to `Array.from`.

My question is, is this a bug in the Array.from polyfill, in that it doesn't properly process a native (not polyfilled) Set, or is the problem with the Babel code, in that `Array.from(x)` is not a perfect equivalent for `...x` (when x is not an array).

Comment: Trying that code in the ["Try it Out"](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=let%20arr%20%3D%20%5B0%2C1%2C2%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20s%20%3D%20new%20Set(arr)%3B%0A%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20%5B...s%5D%3B%0Aalert('3%20%3D%3D%20'%20%2B%20arr2.length)%3B) on Babel's site in Chrome 44 produces `3 == 3`. Are you sure you've set up your polyfills properly?

Comment: @loganfsmyth - funny - I was conditionally loading the babel polyfill if missing Set, Symbol and a few other things I was missing. I manually added the MDN Array.from polyfill so Chrome wouldn't need it. Disabling that and forcing the ES6 shim causes it to work.  Bug must be w/ MDN polyfill.

Comment: Would you mind telling use *which* `Array.from` polyfill you are using? (though I can't see where it's used here). Also, what Chrome version are you on? Mine doesn't support `[...s]` syntax at all.

Comment: Here there is no [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `...x` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Comment: I was using the MDN polyfill.  And yes, I know that's spread.  I feel silly - will edit that.

Comment: Link to MDN Array.from.  Looking in the Core.js version - definitely quite a bit more involved.  Will try to get that built and added.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: @Bergi `Array.from` will be used by the transpiled code Babel creates from `[...]`.

Comment: @torazaburo: Ah, [I see](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=let%20arr%20%3D%20%5B0%2C1%2C2%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20s%20%3D%20new%20Set(arr)%3B%0A%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20%5B...s%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(arr2.length%2C%20%22should%20be%203%22)%3B). The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation) doesn't mention it :-)

Comment: @Bergi Well, it's not part of the spec. It's just the way Babel implements it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can see it producing an empty Array through the call to `Array.from`. Is this a bug in MDN's `Array.from` polyfill?

Not really a bug, but actually [properly documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill):

> *In addition, since true iterables can not be polyfilled, this implementation does not support generic iterables as defined in the 6th edition of ECMA-262.*

I assume that refers to the lack of `Symbol.iterator` in ES5.

Comment: Otherwise ask Jordan Harband, the [author of the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from$compare?to=648147&from=642269) :-)

Comment: It's just baffling to me that because something can't be perfectly polyfilled, they pass on a pretty good one (which works fine with core-js / Babel).